# Spring Batch, transaction and error recovery

Tags: spring, jdbc, transactions, spring-batch, spring-transactions

I have a transaction issue (I think...) with my ItemWriter.

In brief words, I implemented an ItemWriter to insert data in my Oracle DB throw JDBC (I basically use getSimpleJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(myQuery, myObjects)).
As my target table has a foreign key, batchUpdate throw an exception when my data violate this contraint. But all of the data are rejected (including the correct data) so what I need is to insert each item one by one to persist all of the "correct" items, and process the other (for instance, to put a specific log for each incorrect item).

I tried various things, but nothing works:

For each case, my ItemWriter implements ItemWriteListener to process the error in the onWriteError(...) method. I saw the "main transaction" is not commited yet at this point, so waht I wanted to try was suspend this transaction, open a new one to insert each item one by one, come back to the main transaction and let Spring Batch do the rollback of the "main" transaction.

1 - using @Transactional

- I included the tx namespace in my Spring Context to user tx:annotation-driven
- I created a method "create" consisting in: getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, itemValues); to insert a unique item
- I put the 

      @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW) annotation
- I did my ItemWriter implement itemWriteListener to put a for loop in onWriteError(...) which calls my create method

and the result is :

```
    DataSourceTransactionManager:415 - Suspending current transaction, creating new transaction with name [null] 

    DataSourceTransactionManager:204 - Acquired Connection 
    [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:EP, UserName=A1_USER, Oracle JDBC driver] for JDBC transaction

    JdbcTemplate:810 - Executing prepared SQL update

    JdbcTemplate:569 - Executing prepared SQL statement [SQL query...]
```

The execution never ends, it seems to be blocked here (no error message, nothing...). If I put a timeout, I always get a User Interruption... But I don't understand why. I thought as the "main" transaction" is suspended, I can obtain a new one for each item to insert, and that's it... But reality seems to be different.

2- Using the TransactionTemplate object

In this case, I tried :

- to define a transaction template in my onWriteError method (getting my transaction manager from my spring context)
- to set the PropagationBehavior to "requires new".
- to execute a TransactionCallbackWithoutResult which calls my previously defined create method

I get the same result as before.

3- Using Connection and PrepareStatement objects

As I'm desperate (and not very familiar with transactions...), I tried to use the basic JDBC call. To resume it, open a Connection inside my for loop, prepare my statement, execute the statement, commit and close everything. 
But i got the same thing.

I can see that some other people are facing the same issue, but I can't find any solution... So please, if you think you can help me...

Comment: Suggestion - don't mess with the TX logic in Spring Batch (unless you know exactly what you are doing). If I understand your question, you are using DB constrains as a sort of item validation. This is a bad approach. Validate items in item processor instead... use caching for the lookups if necessary. JDBC error is always terminal non-recoverable state (when using transactions)... don't try to workaround this fact.

Comment: If you are not familiar with TX in Spring Batch I strongly suggest to go through the following blog post (it has 3 parts) - https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-1-the-basics/ . You should understand why TX handling in a batch process is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But doing the validation in the process force me to request the DB for each item, and I have more than 1 million items to process... In this context, I'd prefer let the DB doing the job and thorw an exception if needed, to deal with the incorrect items blocks only (it shouldn't occur). Another way could be add a step with a jdbc cursor reader to identify those incorrect items, and its processor and writer to delete from DB, log and so on, but I was really interested into understand theses transactions mechanisms and find a solution to my problem...

Comment: Unfortunatelly Spring Batch's design of item processors does not allow "batch" (chunk) processing - only one item at a time is processed. Yes, this makes the validation based on DB lookup harder. However if you are processing items in a well known order, you can implement some sort of *look ahead* cache... we have done this on one project which periodically processes 50 mil items. Interestingly the slowest part was the INSERT (item writer), not the lookup SELECT (slower in the order of magnitude).

Comment: Note, that if your validation errors are **very rare**, Spring Batch can handle these situations.  When an error occurs, the current TX / chunk is simply reverted, the erroneous item is "thrown away" and the chunk gets processed again. Just check the blog I have linked in my second comment.